# How to create a dataframe with date range as values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, pandasql

I have three variables

**csiti - 23454 : (integer)**

**units - [ 11,22,33,44,55,66,77] : (integer list which is of specific length 'n' always )**

**begin_date - '2019-10-16' : (string)**

How do I create a dataframe from this data like

```
csiti     units forecast_date
1928422     11    2019-10-16  
1928422     22    2019-10-17  
1928422     33    2019-10-18  
1928422     44    2019-10-19  
1928422     55    2019-10-20  
1928422     66    2019-10-21  
1928422     77    2019-10-22
```

The `forecast_date` column should be future dates starting from `begin_date` value.

Comment: `df.explode('units')`, then add the respective date range to the forecast date?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) for datetimes with periods parameter by length of values in list `units`:

```
csiti = 23454
units = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
begin_date = '2019-10-16'

df = pd.DataFrame({'csiti':csiti, 
                   'units':units,
                   'forecast_date':pd.date_range(begin_date, periods=len(units))})
print (df.head(10))
   csiti  units forecast_date
0  23454     11    2019-10-16
1  23454     22    2019-10-17
2  23454     33    2019-10-18
3  23454     44    2019-10-19
4  23454     55    2019-10-20
5  23454     66    2019-10-21
6  23454     77    2019-10-22
```

Comment: I think OP wants each units for a future forecast_date. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Updated the expected output in the question.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf - Answer was changed.